# Remove the second instance of a key value pair in a collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections

So I am trying to determine if a app is part of a list of apps that are affected by downstream services. The following code is what I am currently trying to do:

```
  private function createAppArray($apps, $downApps){

        $final = collect([]);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($apps); $i++){
            foreach($downApps as $downApp){
                if($apps[$i]->id == $downApp->aid){
                    $test = collect($apps[$i]);
                    $final->push($test->merge(['status' => 'warning']));
                    $i++;
                } 
            }
        }


        if($final->count() < count($apps)){
            foreach($apps as $app){
                $test = collect($app);
                $final->push($test->merge(['status' => 'success']));
            }
            // dd($final);
        }


        return $final;
    }
```

As you can see from the screenshots below tough, it duplicates the app as both up and down due to me appending the content of `$apps` on the final collection that has the affected apps on it.

[image]

ALso attached is the contents of a `dd($final)`:

[image]

Basically what I need to do is delete the second instance of a app that is repeated within this collection.

So if the `id` is the second occurrence then delete that collection, can anyone help me accomplish this I cant seem to figure it out?

Comment: What about merge the element within himself? Like  $final = $final->merge($final);

Comment: @HugoDias That doubled my collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating 2 separate loops and trying to merge the results, you can cut down on a ton of code just by looping over the entire list of applications (**$apps**) and checking to see if the ID exists in the **$downApps** collection.

```
private function createAppArray($apps, $downApps) {
    $final = collect([]);
    foreach($apps as $app){

        $test = collect($app);

        // check to see if the down apps collection as this app
        if (!$downApps->where('aid', $app->id)->isEmpty()){
            $final->push($test->merge(['status' => 'warning']));
        } else {
            $final->push($test->merge(['status' => 'success']));
        }
    }

    return $final;
}
```

This method makes the logic much easier to read.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do, for some reason my brain just isn't functioning today! Thank you so much, cheers mate!

Comment: Glad to help! I've been there before. Sometimes a 2nd set of eyes helps.